# Blender doesn't support all fps?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

The custom fps system only allows a value that can be created using two numbers with (1) no more than 3 decimal points and (2) values less than 1000.
Let's take for example 
29.970628 a common format in many of my videos.

29970628/1000000
You can't simplify this down to meet those two rules above.

There are many instances where I can't get the fps of my workspace to fit the video. Especially when doing recordings in OBS, I'll choose an fps like 24 and OBS will output something like 24.02145 fps...values that can't be expressed in the framework blender allows as inputs.

I also hate how blender doesn't show the total fps value correctly, but will render it correctly with all the decimal places. This is very confusing. Take for example 5/0.21, when rendered we see it does infact respect the many many decimals of this fps, but you'd never know as the inputs don't show it. So inputs don't seem to accept more than 3 decimal places but outputs will respect more than 3 places.

Comment: Are you sure that blender only retains 3 decimal points?  I believe it displays 3 but maintains more. What happens when you enter 29970628/1000000 into the frame rate?

Comment: Blender uses 32 bit floating point numbers, which means that it displays 3 digits of precision but maintains 5. AFAIK most video processing software truncates 29.970628 to 29.97 or 30.00.

Answer (score -1):

Accuracy up to a thousandth seems to be inherent in Blender and I couldn't find this setting in user prefs or anywhere else. First, Blender is not meant as a 100% video editor. And, second, better accuracy may not be needed for 3D modelling. File this complaint to the devs.

Comment: When suggesting a user should contact the developers, please state *how* they should contact them.